# Validators as Exception methods

Tags: validation, exception, code-organization

picture we have an exception `FooException` and a validator `FooValidator`

```php
<?php
class FooException extends \Exception {}
class FooValidator {
  public static function validate($string) {
    if ('foo' != (string)$string) {
      throw new FooException();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

what if we moved that validation bit into the exception ?

```php
<?php
class FooException extends \Exception {
  public static function validate($string) {
    if ('foo' != (string)$string) {
      throw new static;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This way the exception is the sole responsible of validating code and throw itself when such validation fails. This way you don't need a generic validation class - which usually will contains several methods - or several pairs of FooValidator,FooException classes

disclaimer: this question was written using PHP, but can be applied to any other language